# Android - getSupportFragmentManager from Adapter RecyclerView in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

hi? i have a `Fragment` with `RecyclerView`, on the `Adapter` of `RecyclerView` i want to `setOnClickListener` to open another Fragment, just `getSupportFragmentManager().add()`, but i cant call the support `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

this is my adapter's `Constructor` :

```
fragment1 f1;

public Adapters(Context context){
    f1 = (fragment1)context; //here has error
}
```

this is my `onClickListener` :

```
fragment2 frg = new fragment2();
f1.getSupportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.idLayout, frg).commit();
```

how to getSupportFragmentManager?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, with create new `Object` from `fragment1` and use it to `getSupportFragmentManager`.